# THREE.js renderer.localClippingEnabled has bug when combined with renderer.vr

Tags: three.js, webvr

First to say, glad to see renderer.vr. I was previously using THREE.VREffect combined with THREE.VRControls. .vr is great. But...

I have some clipping planes. Standard usage: array of planes, given to the material. Mostly works fine*. I have a cube of the things.

Problem: when I use it in VR, I get a different result for my left eye and right eyes! It is off to the "left" of my head. I am guessing this is not on my end, and happenning because the positions of the clipping planes are affected by the camera position. Here's the repo in which it is happenning https://github.com/hamishtodd1/CVR and if you see what it's about you'll see why clipping planes are important for me...

*actually another thing about clipping planes: the constant term feels to me like I have to set it to the negative of what it ought to be. I'm used to this now, but just thought I'd say!

Comment: This seems like a bug, might be worth reporting on github.

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bar2jhbm/10/ - look down

Comment: did this glitch get fixed

Comment: Possibly. There was the transition to .xr instead of .vr